# Swift - Labels width is not accurate

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I am using the code to create borders for my labels here:

extension CALayer {

```
func addBorder(edge: UIRectEdge, color: UIColor, thickness: CGFloat) {

    let border = CALayer()

    switch edge {
    case UIRectEdge.top:
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height: thickness)
        break
    case UIRectEdge.bottom:
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.height - thickness, width: self.frame.width, height: thickness)
        break
    case UIRectEdge.left:
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: thickness, height: self.frame.height)
        break
    case UIRectEdge.right:
        border.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.width - thickness, y: 0, width: thickness, height: self.frame.height)
        break
    default:
        break
    }

    border.backgroundColor = color.cgColor;

    self.addSublayer(border)
}
```

}

However, when I add this to my layers this is what I get: as you can see, the width is totally messed up [image: as you can see, the width is totally messed up] and the frame.width is inaccurate.

Im not sure why this could be. I don't set the width in my storyboard because I want the label to work for all phone widths.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Is the label being resized after you've added the border layer? You'll need to resize it when the label size changes

Comment: You know what, It may be... give me a minute

Comment: @AshleyMills, no, that's not it. Originally I was setting the border in the custom table view cell so i moved it to my table view after the text field was assigned. This didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

A `CALayer` doesn't automatically resize when its corresponding `UIView` does.
You need to override `layoutSubviews` in the `UIView` and update your borders widths/heights

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    ...resize layer or redraw borders here...
}
```

You could make a `BorderedLabel` subclass of `UILabel` that handled all this logic for you.

**EDIT**

If you don't want to deal with creating a subclass of `UITableViewCell` and adding your own `BorderedLabel` views, you may just need to force the layout before setting the border.

I'm just guessing, since you haven't shared any code, but if you are calling `label.text="4517 Bedford..."` and then`label.layer.addBorder()` all you need to do is call `layoutIfNeeded()` to trigger a layout pass before you `addBorder` method measures the frame size.

```
cell.label.text = "4517 Bedford..."
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
cell.label.layer.addBorder(...)
```

Comment: I am using these labels in a custom table view cell, how could i apply them to all table view cells?